# Cannot connect to Second Generation Cloud SQL database

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

At the moment I am trying to follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/dev-access#gaev2-csqlv2) in order to connect to my **Second Generation Cloud SQL** database. However, my application fails on startup since it cannot connect to it ..

As been told by the documentation, I have added both service accounts

```
my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
1234-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

as **Editor** under [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project).

I am using the IPv4 of the Cloud SQL instance to connect. Here the connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://w.x.y.z:3306/app_db?useSSL=false
```

but in the [Stackdriver Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) view I see:

```
[main] ERROR com.mz.server.BootstrappingServerConfig - Error trying to migrate SQL scripts ..
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1385)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006)
    ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    ...
```

Both instances are in the same region: `us-central1-b` for the compute instances and `us-central1` for the SQL instances.

My **app.yaml** file:

```
runtime: java
vm: true

runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
  server: jetty9

env_variables:
  'ALPN_ENABLE': 'true'   # OPTIONAL

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: mz-test:us-central1:mz-test-cloudsql

health_check:
  enable_health_check: false
```

I am not sure what's wrong here. Am I actually allowed to use the local IPv4 address of the SQL instance?

The documentation actually says

> "*In your application code, connect to the instance by opening a socket with the following name: `/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`*"

But I am not sure what that would mean for the connection string.

I am also missing the information about what username/password is required or do I not need one here?

Why am I not able to connect?

Comment: In my case the problem was <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408149/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-which-hosted-in-google-instance/48065029#48065029">Firewall</a>.

Answer (score 2):

For Java applications running on App Engine Flexible Environment applications use the following library: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory