# Can't connect to MYSQL server which hosted in google instance

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I got a google cloud platform - compute engine instance, which I installed MySQL server on.

And now I can't get any signal of life our of the VM the sql installed on,
for exsample:

```
package com.company;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

public static void connection(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("in conncection");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void connectToMySQL(){
    connection();
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://hotsIP:3306/DBname";
    String user = "user";
    String pass = "password";
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,pass);
        System.out.println("???");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    connectToMySQL();
}
}
```

It's take a few second like he trying to connect and the EXEPTION

```
in conncection
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

What I done to make it work:

- in the my.conf:`bind address = 0.0.0.0`, `skip-external-locking comment out`
- restart the server
- looked if the server is active
- looked if the server listening to the port
- looked if its TCP

I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: put `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` before `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,pass);` don't use a separated method to load your driver `connection();` another option, try without loading your driver since 2007 you don't need to load your driver, another thing your jdbc connection version is old, try to upgrade it to a new version and check the difference

Comment: thanx for commenting, but same EXEPTION

Comment: what exception you get explain more?

Comment: the intelliJ say "Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Comment: did you change the driver or what you change?

Comment: i mooved the driver out of the other method "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,pass);
            System.out.println("???");"

Comment: ok can you ping your server and check if the server response or not, if you want to check it grammatically you can use this piece of code http://stackoverflow.com/a/40571839/5558072 to check your server response

Comment: i ren the code u gave me and its returning "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" - and false in the end

Comment: good, then your connection between you and between your server is not enabled, so you have to check your connection first maybe your server is not alive, or you don't have permission to access to this server, another thing, you can open your cmd or terminale and make this command `ping server_ip` and check what it return

Comment: i got this when i try to ping "reply from hostIP bytes = 32 time = 79 ms TTL = 56" 4 rows like this then "sent 4 packets , recived 4 + im probbly need to metion that i also installed apatche tomcat witch is working perfectyl + what is premission im connecting with root and i created a new user with all the previliges still nothing

Comment: ok with your OS you can ping, but with your program no, what is that mean, check the port number maybe!!

Comment: Checked 9 times in deferen methods it's on 3306 the default one

Comment: mmm, ok did you changed your jdbc-connector change it to a new version for example you can use maven dependency and you can download the jar if you don't use maven from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6

Comment: same EXCEPTION "Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Comment: i discovered now when i scanning with nmap all the ports he didn't say that the port 3306 is opend!!! how can i open this port?

Comment: but in my server when look witch port is listening i see tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Comment: mm, i don't think you need to open the port in your side

Comment: So what u suggest me to do next? Plz man I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: can you be patient and learn this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: sorry but nothing helps me i figured that when i put port 80 the EXCEPTION is changed and its says that "Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Comment: Been there did that.. if I deploy my spring boot web app on apache tomcat server and that server heve MySQL server install on if I put localhost in the property's file it will work??

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the following change to your `my.cnf` file

`my.cnf`

```
bind-address = www.000webhost.com (OR)
bind-address = xx.xx.xx.xx (IP Address)
```

You need to restart your MySQL service, once this setting is changed.

Also worth noting is the point that MAMP/ MAMP Pro sets `MAMP_skip-networking_MAMP` by default. You've to disable this line in your `my.cnf`

And if you don't have any user login issues, you should be able to connect to the MySQL Database from your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the root cause was: **Firewall.** I was trying to run the application at work.

What was interesting is that the App Engine Standard running locally actually generated a non-error log in [Google Cloud Platform Logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer), making me discard the firewall hypotheses.

**Solution:** I found out bringing my notebook from home and connecting to company's network, did not work. When I connected to the shared connection in my mobile, worked perfectly.